# Can I make GetOpenFileName return paths longer than MAX_PATH?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm using the [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, or in my case MFC's CFileDialog to open files, pretty much like it's [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dk77e5e7%28VS.90%29.aspx) (except for a single file selection -- i.e. I provided my own longer buffer in `m_ofn.lpstrFile`.)

It works fine, except when a user picks a file whose path becomes longer than `MAX_PATH - 1` (or 259) characters. In that case the following happens:

- On my Windows 8.1, it converts the user selected path into an archaic 8.3 short file format: `"C:\TESTDE~1\NEWFOL~1"`
- On Windows XP I can't even select anything, I get this:

[image]

So I'm curious, since the OS itself supports long Unicode paths, prefixed with `\\?\` (including XP) is there any way to coax GetOpenFileName to return paths in that format as well and not be limited by 259 characters?

Comment: Did you use `OFN_LONGNAMES`?

Comment: @MariusBancila: [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms646839.aspx). `OFN_LONGNAMES` only applies to an old-style dialog to turn off 8.3 filenames. It does not enable the dialog to use `\\?\`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows file dialogs, even the new Vista `IFileDialog`, will not return file names longer than `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: `\\?\ ` only applies to low-level file I\O functions, like `CreateFile()`.  It does not apply to higher level APIs, like Shell interfaces and dialogs.

Comment: That is a choice made by the implementors of the shell and associated dialogs. It is plausible that they may have elected to allow these dialogs to return `\\?\` escaped file names. But they did not.

Comment: I think [this quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) sums it up: "The shell and the file system have different requirements. It is possible to create a path with the Windows API that the shell user interface is not able to interpret properly". `\\?\ ` only applies to the file system, not to the UI. Sure, UI implementors *could* support the syntax, but they *don't*. Different layers of programming.

Comment: Layers don't come into it. They just chose not to support `\\?\`.

Comment: Windows 10 insider builds now have a group policy that allows > MAX_PATH paths even without the \\?\ prefix and Explorer is going to support them so things will change at some point...